# Image is overlapping border, Not sure if i'm doing it correctly

Tags: html, css, image, border

I just started doing HTML/CSS, So please correct me if i have made any huge mistakes in my code.

The problem is as seen on this picture (Sorry about the some of the black boxes, that was just to hide some content, it's only the image at the top that is the problem)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3YrZ.png

You can see that the picture is overlapping the border. So i'm wondering if there is any way to to fix that with CSS, or do i have to edit the picture so it fits with my border corners?

[Here is the code](https://gist.github.com/4060292)

I have done some research throughout the internet, i might have an idea about it's something to do with my position absolute or/maybe relative? But i'm not sure at all, so i hope you guys can help me along

Comment: Try to add `overflow: hidden;` on your wrapper that has the rounded corners.

Comment: @McMastermind That still didn't work. (Google-Chrome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try giving "header" the same border radius at the top as your wrapper element has and adding overflow:hidden. I think that may work.

```
#header {
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 50px;
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 50px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft: 50px;
 -moz-border-radius-topright: 50px;
 border-top-left-radius: 50px;
 border-top-right-radius: 50px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

As an aside your use of absolute positioning for your site is not needed.

To center your site just give your #wrapper element "margin:0 auto;"

All of your orther elements are using absolurte positiong as well. Just let them flow one after another and use floats - don't use absolute positioning to achieve layout like this.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the tips on the layout. Although the image still overlaps with the border. Even with overflow: hidden on and header changes EDIT: I got it to work! Thank you :)

Comment: Strange, here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/beA9B/ - You're not looking at in IE 6/7/8 are you?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using "border-radius" - which is a css3 property, then you could also use "**background-clip**" which effectively sets the background clipping.

There are three available values for this property are:

border-box, content-box or padding-box

I think you will find the one you are looking to use **content-box** (as below).

```
#header {background-clipping:content-box}
```

There is a great article on [css tricks](http://css-tricks.com/transparent-borders-with-background-clip/) take a look. Worth a bookmark too, it is a great source of information to help grow your css / html knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

This looks a little homework-ey, so I won't write code.

But, you do have a few options to round the corners of the image.
I'll list them in order of ease:

- Set the image as a `background-image` of the header.
- Set the style of the image to have rounded corners.
- (Don't do this one) Create a transparent image with already rounded corners.

Comment: It's my own home-website that i use for learning :) But the second point what was did it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Glad I could help. :{D